# Has anyone used the Glimmer tool from MIX labs, what is the general opinion?

Tags: jquery, ide

Mix Labs have released the [Glimmer app](http://visitmix.com/lab/glimmer), an IDE for making fancy effects with jQuery.  I downloaded it & I've done a few things with it.  I think it's quite nifty, but I'm not sure I'd use it 'in real life'.  What's the general opinion on its usefulness & the quality of the code it generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second I saw this I had a bad feeling. This app is exactly the same as the WYSIWYG apps we're told to stay away from. Plus I don't see a niche for it - if you're a web developer then you certainly shouldn't be using it; take the time and do it yourself.

I'm curious what kind of code this app churns out; could you shed some light on that?

The fact is, any JavaScript enhancements added to your site should be fully managed and understood by the web developers implementing them. JavaScript is not a toy; it's not just for making things dance around on screen; it's a programming language with design patterns, methodologies, paradigms etc. You can't just abandon all that and assume it's all about the resulting effect.

If you're serious about what you do then you won't use apps like these..

---

Plus, jQuery is insanely easy to use for a newbie so why on earth would someone need to use this application?